# Combining files based on a date range

Tags: python, bash, unix, python-datetime

I'm very new to scripting and as a result am not sure how best to merge a series of files. I'm attempting to create a Quality Control script that makes sure a nightly load was properly uploaded to the DB (we've noticed that if there's a lag for some reason, the sync will exclude any donations that came in during said lag).

I have a directory of daily synced files labeled as such:

```
20161031_donations.txt

20161030_donations.txt

20161029_donations.txt

20161028_donations.txt

etc etc
```

Every file has the same header.

I'd like to merge the last 7 days of files into one file with just 1 header row. I'm mostly struggling with understanding how to wildcard a date range. I've only ever done:

```
for i in a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
do this 
done
```

which is fine for a static merge but not dynamic to integrate into a proper QC script.

I have a unix background but would like to do this in python. I'm new to python so please be explanatory in any suggestions.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. If you have attempted to write something and have some difficulties, then show what you have done and ask a specific question.
Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips. If you just want free work done then StackOverflow isn't the place for such requests.
Learn to write your code yourself or pay someone to write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Alex Hall's answer, you can grab the header from one file and skip it for the remaining files to do the merge

```
from glob import glob
from shutil import copyfileobj

files = sorted(glob('*_donations.txt'))[-7:]

# if you want most recent file first do
# files.reverse()

with open("merged_file.txt", "w") as outfp:
    for i, filename in enumerate(files):
        with open(filename) as infile:
            if i:
                next(infile)              # discard header
            copyfileobj(infile, outfile)  # write remaining
```

Comment: I've only ever used the function by assigning it to something. It `myfile= open('file.txt','wb')
myfile.write([some SQL output])`
does using open in this fashion write the data to the file so I can use it later in my script?

Comment: Do you mean the `with` statement? `with open("merged_file.txt", "w") as outfp:` opens the file and assigns the file object to `outfp`. Its useful because it will automatically close the file when you drop out of the clause. If you do `myfile= open('file.txt','wb')` ... but don't eventually do `myfile.close()` data will remain unflushed in that file. This script will write to the file and it will be there on disk when its done.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of your date format (assuming it has zero padding, e.g. `20160203` for 3rd Feb) is that it can be sorted alphabetically! So you can just do this:

```
from glob import glob

for path in sorted(glob('*_donations.txt'))[-7:]:
    with open(path) as f:
        # get the content for merging
```

This will get the 7 most recent files, starting with the oldest. [This is why ISO 8601 is the best date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Comment: I'm still not sure how to actually merge the files though. How would this work in conjunction with sed (to strip header rows) or cat to combine the files?

Comment: I don't personally like mixing up languages. You said you were able to do a static merge, so show an attempt.

Comment: Sure. so I normally would do something like: `head -1 file1.txt > headers.tmp sed -i ‘1d’ *.txt cat headers.tmp *.txt > FINAL.txt` or `head -1 file1.txt > headers.tmp for FILE in file1 file2 file3 do sed -i ‘1d’ ${FILE}.txt >> headers.tmp done` something like that...but it 1) doesn't answer the date question and 2) isn't dynamic. I have to manually indicate the files instead of trying to tell it it look at the last 7 days

Comment: @JayA - this code gets the list of files, sorts them from least to most recent and then grabs the last 7. That is dynamic. Run every week, it would get unique nightly logs.

Comment: Gotcha. I was confused how the bit you posted stripped the headers. Can I put that piece of the code after your `with open(path) as f"`? Thanks again!